# MongoDB PHP driver is not compiling on Mac OSX Mavericks

Tags: php, macos, mongodb, osx-mavericks

I am not able to compile MongoDB PHP driver on OX 10.9  , it stops at the line **"checking for ANSI C header files..."**

```
./configure 
.
.
. 
checking for ld used by cc... /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld) is GNU    ld... no
checking for /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for BSD-compatible nm... /usr/bin/nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for ANSI C header files...
```

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to install XCode again after upgrading to Mavericks.
Although that is a weird place to "stop" on, but I guess your environment is a little twisted by the Mavericks upgrade.

That was atleast the solution for [Stuck on PHP Mongo install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19902113/stuck-on-php-mongo-install) - although it didn't stop in the same place..