# Stuck on PHP Mongo install

Tags: mongodb

Not sure if I am in a right place to ask, but I have a problem on installing php mongo.
Here's what I have. I'm on a OSX Mavericks and have mongoDB installed and working. Now when I do the `sudo pecl install mongo`, it gives the following output and gets stuck infinitely:

```
downloading mongo-1.4.5.tgz ...
Starting to download mongo-1.4.5.tgz (141,417 bytes)
..............................done: 141,417 bytes
84 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20100412
Zend Module Api No:      20100525
Zend Extension Api No:   220100525
building in /private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootOyPUZ5/mongo-1.4.5
running: /private/tmp/pear/install/mongo/configure
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... i386-apple-darwin13.0.0
checking host system type... i386-apple-darwin13.0.0
checking target system type... i386-apple-darwin13.0.0
checking for PHP prefix... /usr
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/include/php
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking if awk is broken... no
checking whether to enable Mongo extension... yes, shared
checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no
checking whether to compile for recent osx architectures... yes
checking whether to include code coverage symbols... no
checking Build with PHP streams support... yes
checking for ld used by cc... /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... no
checking for /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for BSD-compatible nm... /usr/bin/nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
```

Previously I had successfully installed on older OSX version. So what might be the problem?
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appeared that the new XCode was needed with it's command line tools. Just installed XCode 5 and everything went fine.